# Why is this error not letting me async render Vue Components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, vuejs3, lazy-loading

I'm quite new with Vue, and I'm trying to lazy load a Component, I'm getting this error which I don't understand, there should probably be a syntax error.
Here's the code:

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Async testing</h1>
    <button @click="showModal=!showModal">show modal</button>
    <Modal v-if=showModal />
    </div>
    
</template>

<script>

import { defineAsyncComponent, ref } from 'vue';
    export default {
        components: {
          Modal: () => defineAsyncComponent(
            () => import('@/components/Modal.vue')
          )
        },
        setup(){
            const showModal = ref(false);
            return {
                showModal
            }
        }
    }
    
</script>
```

The Modal Comp is just a simple h2 and a p with a red border (I already tried the same code without lazy load, and it works fine).
Here's the error:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By wrapping `defineAsyncComponent()` in a function, you're incorrectly declaring the `Modal` component as a function:

```js
export default {
  components: {
        /*  don't do this */
    Modal: () => defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/Modal.vue'))
  },
}
```

The simplest solution is to remove the function wrapper:

```js
export default {
  components: {
    Modal: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/Modal.vue'))
  },
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-render-async-component?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FModal.vue,src%2FApp.vue)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're mixing composition and options API

Try the following in the `<script>`

```
import { defineAsyncComponent, ref } from 'vue';
export default {
    setup() {
        const Modal = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/Modal.vue'));
        const showModal = ref(false);
        return {
            showModal,
            Modal
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just went to the docs to check the composition API way, exact same as you posted, but I'm getting this new console warn which not let me render the Component

Comment: runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:38 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: Modal
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
  at <About onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< Proxy {…} >

Comment: @TomasGilAmoedo - sorry, typo on my part (I blindly copied some of your code) - let me fix (the `() =>` was incorrect)

Comment: If you're using the `setup()` hook, it's totally fine to use the `components` option to declare components, which would be cleaner here IMO. The only things that should not be mixed between `setup()` and other options is: `data`, `methods`, `computed`, `mixins`, `provide`, `inject` (I think that's it).

Comment: @tony19 - yes, I see now that the only issue was the `() =>` - thanks for teaching me something today  though, I use `<script setup>` almost exclusively fo even cleaner code

Comment: Afaik script setup automagically registers components in `components`. It's useful but as with any syntax sugar, it requires to learn what exactly is code that it generates, and that's poorly documented. The problem is that without `components` you can't use `<Modal>` in a template, only as `<component :is=Modal>`

Comment: Are you sure about that @EstusFlask? The above code works for me

Comment: Yes, quite sure, been there already when dealing with dynamic comps. https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-c6zubb?file=src%2FApp.vue . I wonder under which conditions it can be workable